# Maxima & minima of an array

Tags: c, arrays

An array of n numbers is given, where n is an even number. The maximum as well as the minimum of these n numbers needs to be determined.I need to know the comparisions needed?

Comment: Hint: 3*n/2-2 comparisons are enough.

Comment: @Henrik can you please elaborate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in O(n) time.

You can check out this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-and-minimum-in-an-array/) for reference

Comment: You are kidding right? Using naive approach it can be done in O(N)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev:- Please correct me if I am wrong but I have considered it a 2D array. So is it possible in 2D  array also i.e, O(n) time?

Comment: `An array of n numbers is given, where n is an even number. The maximum as well as the minimum of these n numbers needs to be determined.` I don't see any mention of 2D here. OP asks for a way to find minimum and maximum number out of n numbers using minimal number of comparisons

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev:- Thanks a lot Sir. I have checked on net also and updated my answer as well. Thanks for updating me as well :)

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using `3*n/2-2` comparisons.

For `n == 2`, simply compare the two numbers.
Now suppose we have minimum and maximum for the first `n-2` numbers. Compare the remaining two numbers, then compare the bigger one to the previous maximum and the smaller to the previous minimum.

Answer (score 1):

For an unsorted array it can be done in approximately `1.5n` comparisons. You can do it by comparing pairs of elements of an array and storing the `min` and local `max`. You have done `n/2` comparisons to find (locals) max and `n/2` to find the min. Thus, a total of `n` in this phase.

Now you go over the max and min locals and find the global max and min. This would also take `n/2` comparisons. Thus `n + n / 2 = 1.5n`.

If the array is sorted you can find it without any comparisons, since the lowest number is on position 0 and the highest on the position N - 1.